# DataGrid to CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, datagrid, csv

I am binding a DataTable to a DataGrid, everything is working fine.
My next step is to export the **DataGrid data to a CSV** file, comma delimited.

What is the best/easiest way doing this with **ASP.Net 3.5**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used this Snippet to export a DataGrid To CSV. Maybe it helps:

```
public void OnExportGridToCSV(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/GridData.csv"), false);
    // First we will write the headers.
    DataTable dt = ((DataSet)grid1.DataSource).Tables[0];

    int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
        if (i < iColCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    // Now write all the rows.
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
            {
                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
            }
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator);
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Oh, one thank. Use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator

to get the right ListSeparator. We here in europe use semicolon  :)

Comment: If fields contain ,(;) or " your CSV file will be malformed.