# Line breaks lost when exporting datagrid to excel in CSV format WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagridview

This works fine, assuming there are no line breaks in certain cells.

```
        dgvResults.SelectAllCells()
        dgvResults.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(Nothing, dgvResults)
        Dim result As [String] = DirectCast(Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), String)
        Clipboard.Clear()
        dgvResults.UnselectAllCells()

        Try
            Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\export.csv")
            file.WriteLine(result)
            file.Close()
            Process.Start("c:\export.csv")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
        End Try
```

This is how I add line breaks

```
        Dim x As New List(Of String)
        For Each item In res.Properties("proxyaddresses")
            x.Add(item)
        Next
        AllSMTPAddresses = String.Join(ControlChars.Lf, x)
```

When I export this, it doesn't take into consideration there are line breaks, and completely ignores them... so the excel formatting is a little wonky. I've tried: Environment.NewLine, vbCrLf, and now ControlChars.Lf. I think excel doesn't know what to do with the line breaks, so it just does w.e it wants, and creates new rows with them.

Any idea on how I would attack this?

Updated results @Jimmy

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like...

[image]

Comment: Assuming there are no commas in the data, does `result = """" & result.Replace(",", """,""") & """"` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this will be possible without modifying those rows prior to the export.  I found some example code that may help,

```
  Public Sub writeCSV(grid1 As Object, outputFile As String)
    ' Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(outputFile)
    ' First we will write the headers.
    Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(grid1.DataSource, DataSet).Tables(0)

    Dim iColCount As Integer = dt.Columns.Count
    For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
        sw.Write(dt.Columns(i))
        If i < iColCount - 1 Then
            sw.Write(",")
        End If
    Next
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
    ' Now write all the rows.
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
            sw.Write("""") 'lets encapsulate those fields in quotes, quoted csv file!
            If Not Convert.IsDBNull(dr(i)) Then
                sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())
            End If
            sw.Write("""")
            If i < iColCount - 1 Then
                sw.Write(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator)
            End If
        Next
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
    Next
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

[modified from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090628/datagrid-to-csv-file)

Comment: That would work if it was a DataGridView, i'm using a DataGridControl.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't interpret this as a dataview?  I know that's a separate thing.  Did you test this with your existing control?

Comment: `writeCSV(dgvResults, "c:\export.csv")`

Comment: I know how to use it @Jimmy Smith, it's for an entirely different control. For example, datagrid doesn't have the following members... rowcount, nor cells. I can get around the rowcount by using items.count, but not cells. Headertext is also not a member of "datagrid", but can use header instead. I'm using a WPF datagrid btw, not a winforms datagridview.

Comment: With this in mind, I had to dramatically change the answer.  This code has to access the underlying datasource instead.

Comment: I've updated my post to show you what it's doing. It's still displaying the same incorrect results.

Comment: When it's in the grid, those SMTPs are shown in the same cell though?  Maybe I'm replacing the wrong character, could you try the replaceMe with vbLf ?

Comment: The SMTP is the same cell yes. They get posted as if they are there own row, instead of the line feed.

Comment: vbLf works, Kind of... isntead of putting each smtp on new line, it just does an entire line.

Comment: I've updated the top picture to show what it's doing now. It displays them all on the same row now, but no LF. I think we're close :)

Comment: Now that I know they are Lf versus CrLf - let's do an experiment.  I think we can get this if we tweak the CSV's encoding.  remove `.replace(replaceMe, vbnullstring)` and change `Dim sw As New StreamWriter(outputFile)` to `Dim sw As New StreamWriter(outputFile, false, Encoding.Default)`  then test this file in Excel.  If this works, we can go with your original code and just change your output a little.

Comment: It went back to 100% broken, where the linefeeds, are on new rows again.

Comment: Let's try Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250").  Explanation, if you take a file with newlines in the rows and save this from Notepad, it allows you to open it in Excel and see the file as you want.  So we're trying to leave the newlines, but to get it to interpret it as a Windows file.

Comment: Ok @TonyW I have reworked my solution to trick it by using a formula within that specific column.  There *still* has to be another way, but let me know how this looks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118447/discussion-between-tonyw-and-jimmy-smith).

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, you're amazing! @Jimmy Smith